# Curl 7.12.0 or later is required for timestamping support

Tags: curl, ubuntu-12.04, libcurl

configure: error: **Curl 7.12.0 or later is required for timestamping support**

I have this message while trying to `./configure` another package.
CURL is installed

There is an output of

```
benny@ubuntu:$>  apt-cache search libcurl
gnupg - GNU privacy guard - a free PGP replacement
libcurl3 - Multi-protocol file transfer library (OpenSSL)
libcurl3-dbg - libcurl compiled with debug symbols
libcurl3-gnutls - Multi-protocol file transfer library (GnuTLS)
libcurl3-nss - Multi-protocol file transfer library (NSS)
libcurl4-gnutls-dev - Development files and documentation for libcurl (GnuTLS)
libcurl4-nss-dev - Development files and documentation for libcurl (NSS)
libcurl4-openssl-dev - Development files and documentation for libcurl (OpenSSL)
python-pycurl - Python bindings to libcurl
python-pycurl-dbg - Python bindings to libcurl (debug extension)
fp-units-net - Free Pascal - networking units metapackage
fp-units-net-2.4.4 - Free Pascal - networking units
gnupg-curl - GNU privacy guard - a free PGP replacement (cURL)
libcupt2-0-downloadmethod-curl - alternative front-end for dpkg -- libcurl download method
libcurl-ocaml - OCaml curl bindings (Runtime Library)
libcurl-ocaml-dev - OCaml libcurl bindings (Development package)
libghc-curl-dev - GHC libraries for the libcurl Haskell bindings
libghc-curl-doc - Documentation for the libcurl Haskell bindings
libghc-curl-prof - Profiling libraries for the libcurl Haskell bindings
libghc-hxt-curl-dev - LibCurl interface for HXT
libghc-hxt-curl-doc - LibCurl interface for HXT; documentation
libghc-hxt-curl-prof - LibCurl interface for HXT; profiling library
liblua5.1-curl-dev - libcURL development files for the Lua language version 5.1
liblua5.1-curl0 - libcURL bindings for the Lua language version 5.1
libwww-curl-perl - Perl bindings to libcurl
tclcurl - Tcl bindings to libcurl
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found it:

```
 sudo apt-get install libcurl4-gnutls-dev
```

solves the problem.....

Comment: This worked for me on Ubuntu 12.04.2 which was needed to build osslsigncode-1.5.2

Comment: @AlainO'Dea You have a spelling mistake, you mean: `sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev`

Comment: I _strongly_ recommend against using GnuTLS. It's very unsound.  I recommend doing **sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev** instead. http://www.zdnet.com/article/gnutls-big-internal-bugs-few-real-world-problems/